# Use value from previous test

Tags: asp.net, soapui, web-api-testing

I'm using Soap UI Free for testing my ASP.NET web API. I've made a CREATE request to the API and then a test for it and it works - the API saves my data and returns response 200 with some JSON object which also contains the ID value for the newly saved object. How can I use that ID value in the next test which will delete the object?

I found this article on the Soap UI website but it says the technique only applies to Soap UI Pro (which I don't have):
https://www.soapui.org/docs/functional-testing/properties/transferring-properties/

Comment: You can use Groovy Script steps to achieve the same in the free version.  The SmartBear site has some sample scripts (https://www.soapui.org/docs/scripting-and-properties/tips-tricks/).  I'm not sure what you know about Groovy, but it's Java like and you should be able to find sample scripts to save a value from an API response and use it later.  If you get stuck, ask a new question with code snippets, there are plenty of people who will help with Groovy.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the method from the article also applies to the free version of SoapUI. It just doesn't say that and even though it mentions how to perform it, it doesn't really explain, how exactly.

You just have to right-click on a test case and then choose `Add Step -> Property Transfer`.

In the property transfer set-up window:

- you have to provide a JsonPath to the value to retrieve (eg. $.data.id),
- and then the parameter in the next API call to which you want the value to be copied.

So, if you call a CREATE and receive a response with a Json object:

```
{ "data":
    { "id": "fhiugreuuieryiuweyr893ry9yr43"
    }
}
```

you can then set up the Property Transfer step by typing `$.data.id` in the Source section's text field and typing "id" in the Property field in the Target section (which could be your eg. READ, UPDATE or DELETE call).

[image]

And your tests tree will look eg. like this:
[image]